# The formula in this cell refers to a range that has additional numbers adjacent to it

Tags: excel

I can turn off this error warning in preferences, but Excel will still not allow me to sum some of these cells:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJrQ1.png)

Can't figure out why some rows work and others don't... driving me nuts! Help!

Comment: One clue is that it's giving me ### for sums over 999... but I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the width of column J! ### means the value is too wide to display!

Numbers/dates that have too many digits to display in the given cell get replaced by hashes, but strings overflow or display as much as possible.

Comment: You won't find a single Excel user who didn't fall for the same problem! Glad it helped!